# ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details in RestComm

Tags: webrtc, restcomm

I am working with restcomm web sdk. I have successfully implemented demo application on my local server but now I am trying to integrate it with my existing web application which will support audio/video calls. But with my existing web application it throws **ICE failed, see about:webrtc for more details** on firefox browser.

I am testing this scenario on my local environment. I can't figure it out why this happened only while I am trying to integrate it with my existing project.

I am new to this so I have no idea to how to handle this exception. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

For better understanding I am posting the ICE stats which was generated by **about:webrtc**

[image]

Comment: Hi aakib, could you also paste the full contents of the web console for this scenario so that I can troubleshoot more? Also, keep in mind that restcomm-web-sdk uses webrtc for media and SIP for signaling. I assume you have a SIP server side component that you connect to, right?

Comment: Yes, I have SIP server side component. In addition I have researched in deep and identify that, there is noting wrong with the code or flow but I am using long(36 characters) login id for SIP account. If I use **bob** or **alice** as login then my application works fine.

Comment: **SIP log on browser console :** SIP message received: SIP/2.0 200 OK
**To: <sip:5bfe10ea-d25b-476f-873e-6517c5a23ebc@192.168.1.119>**;tag=79580131_c1de4f39_57a5b08a_8999b5e4
Via: SIP/2.0/WS 192.168.1.119:34326;branch=z9hG4bK-323332-30429365d0b47fd8aab5c9eabf8bcc9e;rport=34326;received=192.168.1.119
CSeq: 2 REGISTER
Call-ID: 1467793508941
From: <sip:5bfe10ea-d25b-476f-873e-6517c5a23ebc@192.168.1.119>;tag=1467793508960
Server: Restcomm 7.8.0.945
Contact: <sip:5bfe10ea-d25b-476f-873e-6517c5a23ebc@192.168.1.119:34326;transport=ws>;expires=3600
Content-Length: 0

Comment: Aakib, this is just the registration response and I can't tell much from that I'm afraid, can you please paste the whole web console? You can use pastebin or gist to avoid the stack overflow character limit. I don't think there should be an issue with the username length, since registration seems to be handled fine. Finally, one more question I assume you get the issue at the point you make the actual call, right?

Comment: Actually I am facing issue while I have incoming calls, otherwise I can make outgoing calls without any issue. like for console log https://gist.github.com/akoomogul/5d1e2b94eb6a28211aeb96a5a4572740

Comment: Aakib, just had a look at your logs. It's weird that I don't see any errors there in the ICE connectivity part. What is strange though is that in the response to the INVITE there are no candidates in the video SDP section. I assume both caller and callee are using restcomm web sdk, right? Also, could you collect Restcomm logs (RESTCOMM_INSTALLATION/standalone/log/server.log and RESTCOMM_INSTALLATION/mediaserver/log/server.log) and also gather full tcpdump ($ sudo tcpdump -i any -w full.pcap) for the scenario on the Restcomm host and share a link, so that I can dig deeper into your issue?

Comment: Ya atsakiridis I have also tested on olympus for caller and callee both and finally found that, if username or friendly name of sip client is more than 30 characters then then this weird issue occurs. And for log file, standalone/log/server.log file has more than 800k lines if still want to go thought then please share me your email address so I can share you log files. Btw thanks for being helping hand :)

Comment: dump : https://gist.github.com/akoomogul/7e83c8e554f272a1433def2f4773171f media server log : https://gist.github.com/akoomogul/dd2f411af329434e1a2b2465832c3b32 stanalone server log : https://gist.github.com/akoomogul/687b623a580a903d2ef86b1bed9f3e6e

Comment: Can you post your log here, if you find any ip6 error in your log let me know