# How to recover for ICE Failed?

Tags: webrtc

I have developed a WebRTC based sample, but I face problems like `ICE Failed` often, and then the entire app becomes unstable, how/what can I do to recover from this failure? AFAIK this is not related to code(at least I think so) still, if you need my code I can post it here. Further more I have gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38217107/ice-failed-see-aboutwebrtc-for-more-details-in-restcomm) and [google groups email](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/CRHffPWGpg4) but I didn't get much of it. Can anyone please explain this.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do an ICE restart. There is a canonical sample for that available [here](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/restart-ice/)

Comment: I am confused about `offerOptions`, is it something which is deprecated now? along with `offerToReceiveAudio: 1,
offerToReceiveVideo: 1` this too ?